# Объявление типа для переменной с таблица.столбец %TYPE

Tags: oracle, plsql, курсор

Данный скрипт представлен в книге - "Oracle PL/SQL для профессионалов":

```
PROCEDURE explain_joke (main_category_in IN joke_category.category_id%TYPE)
IS
 /*
 || Курсор со списком параметров, состоящим
 || из единственного строкового параметра.
 */
 CURSOR joke_cur (category_in IN VARCHAR2)
 IS
 SELECT name, category, last_used_date
 FROM joke
 WHERE category = UPPER (category_in);
 joke_rec joke_cur%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
 /* Теперь при открытии курсора ему передается аргумент */
 OPEN joke_cur (main_category_in)
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему при объявлении типа для параметра в процедуре `explain_joke` указывается таблица.столбец (`joke_category.category_id`).

Это ошибка или такой вариант объявления переменной разрешен?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не ошибка. Атрибут [%TYPE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/TYPE-attribute.html#GUID-EAB44F7E-B2AB-4AC6-B83D-B586193D75FC) является частью синтаксиса PL/SQL.

Он позволяет объявить константу, переменную, или параметр подпрограммы с тем же типом данных, что и ранее объявленная переменная или столбец таблицы, не зная точно, что это за тип данных.

Если меняется объявление ссылаемого элемента, то соответственно меняется и объявление ссылающегося элемента.

Например:

```
declare
    val varchar2 (8);
    ref val%type := 'abcdef';
begin null;
end;
/
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

А если так:

```
declare
    val varchar2 (4);
    ref val%type := 'abcdef';
begin null;
end;
/
```

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Comment: Здравствуйте. Прошу прощения, я неправильно написал вопрос, хотел спросить почему при объявлении типа переменной указывается таблица.столбец не из запроса, который определяет курсор...

Comment: @AlexKonkin Не совсем понятно: _почему при объявлении типа переменной указывается таблица.столбец не из запроса, который определяет курсор_. Попробуйте переформулировать. У вас нет переменной, тип которой объявлен с таблица.столбец, только один параметр.

Comment: прошу прощения, параметр, который объявлен в процедуре ((main_category_in IN joke_category.category_id%TYPE) имеет не понятно как сформированный для меня тип, не подскажите, почему переменная объявляется именно с таким типом, а не , например, joke.category_id?

Comment: joke_category.category_id и joke.category_id это одно и тоже.  Есть таблица joke_category с первичным ключом category_id, и есть связанная таблица joke с внешним ключом category_id, их типы всегда совпадают. Стало понятней, или остались вопросы?

Comment: Спасибо большое за объяснение.